# Install Postgis in docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker, postgis

I created a database with Docker using the postgres image as usual

```
docker run -d \       
    --name some-postgres \
    -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypassword \
    -v ${HOME}/postgres-data/:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
    -p 5432:5432 \
    postgres
```

now I decided to add a new column in one of the tables to store coordinates using PostGIS, however when I do

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

or something similar I get this error message:

```
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory
```

Is there an additional step one has to take before running the Docker container in order to install PostGIS?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The postgis extension does not come with vanilla postgres, which does ship with a whole bunch of more general purpose extensions, though nothing notable for geospatial. Take a look at this instead: https://registry.hub.docker.com/r/postgis/postgis/

Comment: Thanks, this helped. 
Actually I just needed to run the same command, but using the postgis image and mount the same volume I was using in the vanilla postgres
`docker run -d \       
--name some-other-postgres \
-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypassword \
-v ${HOME}/postgres-data/:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
-p 5432:5432 \
postgis/postgis`

Answer (score 17):

I know that there is already a response but this could help someone

1. Firstly you should already have a **Postgres image** and after a postgres docker container running .

[link 2](https://dev.to/shree_j/how-to-install-and-run-psql-using-docker-41j2)

2. After you should have the **POSTGIS DOCKER IMAGE**

[voir ici] : https://hub.docker.com/r/kartoza/postgis/

3. The image below shows my config after all these steps

[image: link here]

4. After you should stop the running container of postgres which was running at port **5432** for me

this could help: [https://blog.eduonix.com/software-development/learn-stop-kill-clean-docker-containers/#:~:text=To%20stop%20a%20container%20you,the%20killing%20is%2010%20seconds](https://blog.eduonix.com/software-development/learn-stop-kill-clean-docker-containers/#:%7E:text=To%20stop%20a%20container%20you,the%20killing%20is%2010%20seconds).

5. Now we can create the container that is going to link our **postgres container** with our **postgis Extension**

```
sudo docker run -d --name postgis_postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgrespassword -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres  -v /home/judith/Documents/postgres/db-data/:/var/lib/postgresql/data  -p 8000:8000  kartoza/postgis:9.6-2.4
```

Here **/home/judith/Documents/postgres/db-data/** is the path to the database data of postgres container

[image: result of this step here]

6. Now we can enter in the running container created at the step **5** with the command

```
judith@jlas:~$ sudo docker exec -it postgis_postgres bash
root@544c89fadeda:/# //you will be there
```

7. Write the command that is going to link to the postgres console admin , here
   the **5432** is port where my postgres container was running and **postgres** is the admin of my postgres in my config , you will config the database admin in the step 1 do not worry .

```
root@544c89fadeda:/# psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres
```

[image: you can see the result here]

8. After you can create you **POSTGIS EXTENSION**

```
postgres=# CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
CREATE EXTENSION
postgres=#
```