# How do I install postgis on a postgres container running on docker?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, postgis

I'm super new to postgres extensions and docker, and I have some questions regarding how to set them up on a postgres container running on Docker. I have to create a table which will need the geometry type provided by postgis. I have a docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  test-db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '5434:5432'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: testdb
    volumes:
      - ./database/postgres:/data
```

My Dockerfile looks like this currently:

```
# Development Build
FROM node:12.18.3-alpine3.12 as builder
LABEL maintainer="person <person@person.com>"

RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache make git

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ARG NPM_TOKEN

COPY package*.json ./
RUN true
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN true
COPY .npmrc /root/.npmrc

RUN npm i && rm /root/.npmrc && npm run postinstall; exit 0

COPY . .

RUN npm run build:all
```

I also tried following [this](https://diminutive-well-nextjs.vercel.app/blog/setting-up-postgis-on-an-existing-postgres-database-inside-a-docker-container) tutorial but when ran into errors on step 5.

I also tried following the second answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63693539/install-postgis-in-docker-container) Stackoverflow question. But when I tried to run `docker pull kartoza/postgis:image_version`, I got an error `Error response from daemon: manifest for kartoza/postgis:image_version not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown`.

If i install postgis and define it on dockerfile and docker compose and someone else runs my code, will they also need to download postgis?

Comment: There is an [official postgis image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/r/postgis/postgis/). Using that would be the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my recommendation.

## For just PostgreSQL with Postgis

Assuming you are on Linux or Mac, create a directory called `gis` using `mkdir gis` and go into the directory by doing `cd gis`.

Create a file called `Dockerfile.pg`.

```
from postgres
run apt-get update
run apt-get upgrade -y
run apt-get install postgis -y
```

Create a file called `gis.sh` that contains:

```
#!/bin/bash

psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --dbname "$POSTGRES_DB" <<-EOSQL
    create extension postgis;
EOSQL
```

Create a file called `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  gis:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.pg
    container_name: gis
    image: gis
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: test
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
    volumes:
      - pg:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./gis.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/gis.sh
volumes:
  pg:
```

Then, do `docker compose up -d`.

That'll use your Dockerfile.pg to:

- build the postgres image and call it gis
- run apt-get update
- run apt-get upgrade -y
- run apt-get install postgis

It'll create a container and call it `gis`

It'll mount a named volume called `pg` so you can identify the volume easily.

It'll run gis.sh, which will create an extension called postgis after logging into PostgreSQL.

When you do `docker image ls`, you will see a `gis` image.

When you do `docker container ls`, it'll show you the running container name.

You can log on to the container usingi `docker exec -it gis /bin/bash` and you'll see

```
% docker exec -it gis /bin/bash
root@d3bdba37a76b:/#
```

You can verify that the extension has been added by doing:

```
root@d3bdba37a76b:/# psql postgres postgres
psql (15.3 (Debian 15.3-1.pgdg120+1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# SELECT oid, extname, extversion FROM pg_extension;
  oid  | extname | extversion
-------+---------+------------
 13561 | plpgsql | 1.0
 16384 | postgis | 3.3.3
(2 rows)

postgres=# exit
```

Once you are done using the container, you can bring remove the container using `docker compose down -v`. The `-v` will remove the volume as well.

---

## Hint about your app, if you want to run it along with PostgreSQL

While I don't know how your app works, you might want to try something like this to bring up your database and app. Tweak as you deem fit.

In the `gis` directory, you now have 3 files:

- Dockerfile.pg
- gis.sh
- docker-compose.yml

Add another file called `Dockerfile` - that's your app's Dockerfile.

```
FROM node:12.18.3-alpine3.12 as builder
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache make git
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ARG NPM_TOKEN
COPY package*.json ./
RUN true
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN true
COPY .npmrc /root/.npmrc
RUN npm i && rm /root/.npmrc && npm run postinstall; exit 0
COPY . .
RUN npm run build:all
```

Change the docker-compose.yml to:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  gis:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.pg
    image: gis
    container_name: gis
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: test
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
    volumes:
      - pg:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./gis.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/gis.sh
    ports:
      - "5434:5432"

  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: nodeapp
    container_name: nodeapp
    depends_on:
      - gis
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"

volumes:
  pg:
```

Then you can run `docker compose up -d` and see the output.

Here's a blog that could also help you: https://michalzalecki.com/docker-compose-for-nodejs-and-postgresql/

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response!  already have a database container configured in docker-compose.ymal in the root layer of my app. do i need to somehow specify the order of running both compose files? When then i ran docker compose up, it never stops running

Comment: You’ll have one docker-compose.yml file and 2 Dockerfiles. The dockerfiles will have info about how to build an image with your app and postgis. The single compose file will have 2 sections. The order of sections within the compose file won’t matter as long as you use depends_on.